# Latex two captioned verbatim environments side-by-side

Tags: layout, latex, tex, verbatim

How to get two verbatim environments inside floats with automatic captioning side-by-side?

```
\usepackage{float,fancyvrb}
...
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{filecontents}{Verbatim}%
    {fontsize=\small,
        fontfamily=tt,
        gobble=4,
        frame=single,
        framesep=5mm,
        baselinestretch=0.8,
        labelposition=topline,
        samepage=true}

\newfloat{fileformat}{thp}{lof}[chapter]
\floatname{fileformat}{File Format}

\begin{fileformat}
    \begin{filecontents}
    A  B  C
    \end{filecontents}
    \caption{example.abc}
\end{fileformat}

\begin{fileformat}
    \begin{filecontents}
    C  B  A
    \end{filecontents}
    \caption{example.cba}
\end{fileformat}
```

So basically I just need those examples to be side-by-side (and keeping automatic nunbering of caption). I've been trying for a while now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the soulution finally.

```
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{fileformat}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{filecontents}
    A B C
    \end{filecontents}
    \captionof{fileformat}{example.abc}
  \end{minipage}
  \quad
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{filecontents}
    C B A
    \end{filecontents}
  \captionof{fileformat}{example.cba}
  \end{minipage}
\end{fileformat}
```

The problem solution is to make a caption independently from environment using `caption` package macro `\captionof{fileformat}{Our Caption}`.

Answer (score 4):

For captioning `verbatim` environments you can either use `listings` (which will offer much more than just plain captioning, syntax highlighting and line numbering come for free too) or define your own `float` environment using the [package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) with the same name.

An example (from [WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{document}

\begin{program}
  \begin{verbatim}

class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display the string
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{verbatim}
  \caption{The Hello World! program in Java.}
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm already using listing package for formatting algorithms, but I'm not aware that there is a possibility to define multiple automatic captioning. (Like different counting for "Algorithm" and "Format").
Also I wouldn't still know how to put those two verbatim environments side-by-side.

Answer (score 2):

Use minipage like in this example, which places two pictures side by within a figure float with separate captions

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{5 cm}
    \includegraphics{filename 1} 
    \caption{caption 1}
    \label{labelname 1}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{5 cm}
    \includegraphics{filename 2}  
    \caption{caption 2}
    \label{labelname 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Sure but how do I get the correct automatic captioning? Figure does it correctly but displays wrong prefix for captions. If I use fileformat instead of figure - it displays only one of the captions.

Comment: Ah, I think that's the float package defining it's own caption placement styles. Have you tried the different \floatstyle{} options?

Comment: Yes, tried - ruled, plain, boxed. It's seems that if I'm not using figure it doesn't recognize those as being two separate things.

Comment: Are you using figures at all? Would it be easier to modify the Figure environment than to try and get this working with the float package?

Comment: Yes I'm using figures, two custom floats and lstlisting.

Comment: OK, a very kludgy way of doing what you want would be to use the float packages H option which makes it so that you can place the float exactly where you want it. Use the multicol package and switch to \twocolums, place two fileformat floats with the H option, and then switch back to \onecolumn.